# Android Mobile: Flex Image control showing missing image

Tags: c#, android, image, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I use a Flex app (SDK version 4.14.1) to take a photo from a camera on Android, and I pass the resulting ByteArray to an .net c# script that writes the image to a directory and sets the name etc.
I can see the file in the file system, I can open the file in the file system (with either a jpg or png extension, I believe that browsers can do this though), but when I add an Image control to Flex and point the source to the path of the image, I just get that annoying missing image icon.

I was guessing that it was to do with extensions, as the image is sent straight from the camera as a byte array I kind of had to guess the extension, but whatever it is can you help me solve it please?

For reference, the image is stored on an IIS web server, but it isn't cross domain policy that is stopping it because if I drag the image into my project and bind it directly it still does the same thing.

Ideally I need to use Image and not BitmapImage, but if it can't be helped then I can change.

Thanks

***EDIT***

Changing from Image to BitmapImage kind of worked, kind of because the image now shows in the desktop debugger, but on device it just shows blank. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I am looking for an answer as to why an image stored on a remote server (even with a crossdomain file set to allow all) would not show in an Image control, but would show in a BitmapImage control if run in the debugger. 
I know I usually sort these kinds of problems out myself, but in this case I have no clue and could do with a pointer please.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of making sure all of my questions get an answer I am going to settle on the solution of using BitmapImage. Every other part of the design is correct, I cannot see anything I am doing wrong, and although using BitmapImage causes me an issue with missing image and placeholder image, it is a solution after all.